# Only last line of Pandas webscraped data is appearing in spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, database

I am new to Python coding and I am trying to get a spreadsheet of basketball stats. Only the first row of pandas output comes out when I try to get a spreadsheet of this data. Anyone know how I can get all inputs to display?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import pandas as pd 
headers = {'User Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

players = [
     'cade-cunningham','jalen-suggs','evan-mobley', 'scotty-pippenjr', 'franz-wagner', 
'davion-mitchell', 'scottie-barnes','moses-moody', 'james-bouknight', 'ziaire- 
 williams', 'corey- kispert', 'tre-mann', 'ayo-dosunmu'
]

for player in players:
        url = (f'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/{player}-1.html')
        res = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
        header = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit = 2)[0].findAll('th')]
        rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
        player_stats = [td.getText() for td in soup.find('tr', id ='players_per_game.2021')]
        print(header)
        print(player_stats)
graph = pd.DataFrame([player_stats], columns = header)
graph
```

The output is just a row of data for the last player and no one else. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And do you understand why?  You're not adding to a list.  Every time through the list, you destroy the previous `player_stats` and create a new one with this row.  You need to add `player_stats = []` before the loop, and use

```
player_stats.append([td.getText() for td in soup.find('tr', id ='players_per_game.2021')])
```

inside the loop